# command line crashing when typing flutter or flutter doctor

Tags: flutter, command-line, crash, flutter-doctor

my command line will close whenever I type flutter or flutter doctor.

I have read or watched solution on the internet telling me that I should put these things : [put these on system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpGU6.png)  on system path but that doesn't work, what should i do? did I miss something?

Answer (score -1):

You should have to set your flutter sdk in env first to execute the command of flutter. Then try to run flutter doctor.